# Solving Error - "An item with the same key has already been added when returning 404"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have my custom error page handler defined like this:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    ...
}
```

Then in error controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(int errorCode)
    {
        switch (errorCode)
        {
            case 404:
                return View($"~/Views/Error/{errorCode}.cshtml");
        }

        return View(errorCode);
    }
}
```

When in production mode everything works fine, but when on develop, there are 2 scenarios:

1. I'm hitting 404 page "just like that" and it's showing my custom 404 page (which is correct)
2. I'm forcing 404 from action eg.

   ```
   if(nothingFound)
   {
       return NotFound();
   }
   ```

   and then it's entering ErrorController action, and even the view (404.cshtml), but after that it prints whole debug titled:

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
>   Key: System.Object

Is it something normal when using `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`, or do I have something miss-configured?

**UPDATE**

Stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.StatusCodePagesExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Are you saying exception message is displayed in development server instead of reaching ErrorController ?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of that exception.

Comment: @Kira yes, but only when I force error using some function eg. NotFound(). When accessing non existing route it's working for both, production and development. I'm totally fine with request not reaching error controller in develop mode, but I'd expect something other than this exception.

Answer (score 8):

I was having similar issue. I found the issue later that it was related to the order of using middleware. I was using middle ware to write response headers like `X-Content-Type-Options` and other headers. I just moved this above the `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` and it start working correctly. So my current code is like:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
            await next();
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
        }
```

Hope this can help any one having similar issue like me.

Comment: Helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Still working in 2022!

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to the call to `UseBrowserLink()`, you can manage this function from the related menù.

If you uncheck the **Enable Browser Link** the error goes away.

[image]

I don't know what cause the issue, but here are the link to the [UseBrowserLink docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink)

Comment: Maybe you can expand your answer to explain what browser link is doing here that causes this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this with `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` which was pointing to an end point that didn't exist, in combination with the fact that I was trying to GET an endpoint marked with `[HttpPost]`.